# Count how many times each value appears in multiple list that's been groupby'ed?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have 'Season','HomeTeam','AwayTeam' in a .csv, which I Groupby into a list based on 'Season'.
I want to count how many times each team names appear in multiple list.

Using:-

```
    clubslist=(epl.groupby(['Season'])['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'].apply(lambda x: pd.unique(x.values.ravel()).tolist()))`
```

```
clubslist
```

```
I was able to get:-
Season
2000-01    [Charlton, Man City, Chelsea, West Ham, Covent...
2001-02    [Charlton, Everton, Derby, Blackburn, Leeds,...
2002-03    [Blackburn, Sunderland, Charlton, Chelsea, Everton...
2003-04    [Arsenal, Everton, Birmingham, Tottenham, Blackburn...
2004-05    [Aston Villa, Southampton, Blackburn, West Bro...
2005-06    [Aston Villa, Bolton, Everton, Man United, Ful...
.
.
.
.
All the way down to:-
2021-22    [Brentford, Arsenal, Man United, Leeds, Burnle...


So for example, based on above 7 Seasons, I want the output to be

Charlton: 3
Chelsea: 2
Everton: 4
Blackburn: 4
Aston Villa: 2
Arsenal: 2
Sunderland: 1
Derby: 1

and so on and so forth.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), see specific details on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
clublist.explode().value_counts()
```

Comment: What a simple solution haha. Thanks a lot!!